# Can murders be committed by more than one person? Can there be more than one victim?

Tags: danganronpa

Unlike the games in [Liar Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_Game), the rules of a Danganronpa game are sometimes made up or stated midway, which for me kind of sucks but is tolerable so long as the rules are consistent.

As far as I know, in Liar Game, the dealers have always accounted for all possible situations so whenever there are changes in the game, they state it outright. For example, in games involving voting, the dealers have stated what happens in the event of a draw.

---

In Danganronpa, can murders be committed by more than one person?

Monokuma stated (albeit midway) that accomplices after the fact are not considered as murderers for their purposes.

What if both A and B hold a single knife together and use it to stab C once resulting in C's death? In that case, am I correct that A and B are both the murderers?*

Perhaps Monokuma will adjust the rules, but I would like to know what are the stated rules regarding this, if any and from any media.

I'm done with the anime. Feel free to spoil other media, but please use spoiler tags.

---

*I'm trying to rule out trick cases like:

1. A and B use one knife each to try to kill C at the same time but then it will turn out that one of them was actually first or the second stab was the one that killed C.
2. A and B say they will kill C together, but B didn't hold the knife firmly so only A is counted as a murderer.

Comment: Maybe you should try letting the series play out. Perhaps it's something that's explained later. Also again, why is this tagged with the "animation-mistakes" tag?

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ Death Note ended with a lot of unexplained stuff in terms of the rules of the DN. People have wild imaginations, especially those who watch  or read a lot of espionage, detective, fantasy, mystery, gaming or thriller stuff.

Comment: That's the thing, there were unresolved points when it *finished*. You haven't *finished* the anime, so you wouldn't know if they did or not.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ And now I'm done soooo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the third case of the first game (and anime), there are two murderers who each actually personally kill someone, but Monokuma states that there is only one culprit: the person who came up with the plan. As such, in your hypothetical situation of A and B stabbing one person with one knife at the same time, if A was the one to initially suggest the murder, then by Monokuma's rules, A alone is the culprit. I believe this would cover most cases of murderers working together, if only on a technicality in some cases; if two people were to come up with a plan to murder someone at the exact same time (wildly unlikely as that is), Monokuma would probably have to make up a new rule for it on the fly, which he does have a habit of doing.

Comment: Thanks E. J. ! By the way, mathematically speaking it's practically impossible (as in [probability zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely#Throwing_a_dart)) that 2 people can come up with plan at the same time.